# stl list iterator of objects pointer

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm read some post about this theme and I don't know, using a stl list of objects pointer, when I want access to element function through an iterator the app get me error run time of null pointer. Would someone help me with that?? I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.
This is part of code:

```
  typedef std::list<Actor> listActors;
  listActors listactors = pMain->Actors();
  listActors::iterator iter = listactors.begin();

std::string nameactor;
nameactor = (*iter)->getName();//Here the app get a run time error of null pointer
```

Comment: It depends entirely on how that list has been populated.  You haven't shown us the code for that.  But my guess is that the first element is a null pointer...

Comment: You store Actor objects in your list, not pointers to Actor objects. That is, you cannot apply the -> operator on the element, so this should throw a compile error. Your code does something like this:
`Actor a; a->getName();`
The correct would be: `Actor a; a.getName();`

Comment: @DavidFrank: With the code as shown, you're correct. Another possibility is that the LarriPapi just didn't show the correct code and that the list truly is a list of pointers. Since we're all just guessing here, my guess is that the list is empty (`begin() == end()`), in which case it is the dereference of `iter` that is invalid.

Comment: Another unlikely possibility is that Actor overloads the -> operator.

Comment: Voting to close as OP has not provided enough information to make it a real question.

Comment: Is `Actor` a pointer? Because if it is not, the last line of your code causes error. If you dereference `iter` then you have to use the dot(.), not the arrow(->) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Vote up this is not an answer. But too long for a comment section.
I will delete when the question gets updated appropriately.

This:

```
typedef std::list<Actor> listActors;
```

Says your list is full of objects of Actor **not** pointers to Actors.

Thus if this:

```
nameactor = (*iter)->getName();
```

compile, then (*iter) is an Actor object and the only way you can use -> on it is if the class overloads the `operator->()` and is returning a pointer that is NULL.

Since we don't have the code for Actor we can't tell your what is going wrong, or **more likely** you have made a cut paste error in creating the question. In which case we can't help either.

You need to write code that we can compile and run to replicate the problem. Them paste the exact code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

`(*iter)->getName();` is wrong.
Your should write either `iter->getName();` or `(*iter).getName();`.